# SQL grouping sets and roundup

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, grouping-sets

I am trying to calculate the difference between a certain sum of values and the same sum using specific roundup rules (columns 5 and 6):

---

```
select
    A,
    B,
    C,
    sum(D),
    sum(D)/300,
    case when sum(D)/300 < 1.5 then 0 else round(sum(D/300), 0) end

from table

group by grouping sets ((A,B,C), ())
```

---

The SQL works, but the final row is wrong. The totals in the final row seem correct for column 4 and 5, but in column 6 is doesn't add up the rounded up values of the column, but the rounded up value of the total of column 5...

What am I doing wrong? (Goal: compare the totals of column 5 and 6)

Any help is welcome!

EDIT:

the result right now is something like this (only column 5 and 6):

1,2   0 
 1,5   2 
 3,1   3 
     
 5,8   6

The total of the second column should say 5 in this example, but it says 6, using the unrounded values...

Comment: If I understand your question, you may be under the impression that the "grand total" for column 6 is calculated from the partial totals for column 6. ("Total" in this context meaning divided by 300 and then rounded unless less than 1.5.)  It isn't - the `sum(D)` used in the column 6 computation for the grand total row is still based on the individual values of D in each row, not on the rounded totals for the partial sums.

Comment: Yes! That is what I expected. So how do I get the total of the rounded values? WIll a subquery on this table use the right numbers or also sill use D?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the outer `SUM`:

```
select
    A,
    B,
    C,
    sum(D),
    sum(D)/300,
    SUM(case when sum(D)/300 < 1.5 then 0 else round(sum(D/300), 0) end) as result

from table

group by grouping sets ((A,B,C), ())
```

Comment: I tried it, but I get the following Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression